How to I fix the buildTarget goal for my app?
I am getting a
The parameters 'buildTarget' for goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.156:build are missing or invalid

error when I rebuild my project before I run the Simulator. I have not changed anything in any of the poms, and I do not know what I had changed in the code when this first appeared.
Any direction would be appreciated.
Here is the Screenshot

Edit 2


Can you copy the full output of the error in the console and include it here. If it's too long you can open a https://gist.github.com and include the link to that.

The only output it gives me is the error message above. The simulator runs and I can still work on my app, but each tim I Rebuild the class I get the error.

Can you include a screenshot of the console? There should be a button there to show the full logs.

Here is the IntelliJ Console log for 12.22.24. I do not see a mention of buildTarget. https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/79cf0173ab4f0dfad029510323ff307d

That doesn't seem to be the output of the maven build. Are you sure you copied the IDE console from the right location?

Added a screenshot. The gist was from the IntelliJ console. As I said in my first comment, this is the only output when I Rebuild the class.

On the left hand side you have a button that lets you toggle the view (I think it's shaped like an eye) that will convert the IDE tree like structure to text that you can copy and paste to a gist.

I ran mvn -e and got the following log: https://gist.github.com/curtjacobs1/d47f4b88665dd2c0eca6d39f59d9ac06

You didn't include the target. Use one of the targets integrated in the IDE and copy the error from the console. Do these targets include an error?
